# jQuery next() not working as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a set of linked images which I want to cycle through every 3 seconds, but only show one at a time:

```
# some django template code:
<div id="featured-prints" class="featured-promo">
    {% for p in promo_prints %}
    <a href="{% url 'print_order_with' p.id %}">
        <img class="featured-print" src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ p.id }}_{{ THUMBNAIL_SIZE }}.png" alt="{{ p.body }}" />
    </a>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

# the JS to cycle through:

$(function(){
    $('.featured-promo a:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.featured-promo :first-child')
        .hide()
        .next('a')
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('.featured-promo');
}, 1000);
```

I recently added the `<a>` around the img, and now the Javascript won't work; it doesn't `fadeIn()` the next linked image. I have tried several variations, including passing "a" to `next()`, and "a img", but nothing seems to work. I have also tried chaining `parent()` to the `hide()` function, still no dice.

Any tips?

Comment: `fadeIn(2000)` - `2000ms` and interval of `1000ms` . That would never work!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you appending stuff over and over to `.featured-promo`? why are you running the interval again before the fade in is complete..? are you aware of what you're doing or are you simply throwing in random query functions..?

Comment: @TilwinJoy What he seems to be doing is fading in the second element, then moving the first element to the end, so the second element becomes the first element. This will keep rotating the carousel.

Comment: @Barmar wah.. didn't notice it properly… thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
$('.featured-promo :first-child')
```

to:

```
$('.featured-promo > :first-child')
```

Without the `>` it goes down to every level. So it finds the first child of `.featured-promo` (the first `a`), and the first child of each `a` (every `img`). It hides all of these, and then only fades in the next `a`. The `img` tags stay hidden, because nothing ever fades them in.

`>` in a selector means just to match the next part against an immediate child, not all descendants.

Comment: This doesn't sort the issue I'm afraid; none of of the images display still. I have tried putting the 'img' and 'a' in the next() call, to no avail.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: @ThePiedPipes this does [sort the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/4TkS4/) as far as i can see..? i couldn't sort out the issue still seeing this post and i'm the one who up voted it… Issue might be something else in your code..?

Comment: @Tilwin Joy have you tried doing your fiddle with `<img>`s not divs?

Comment: @ThePiedPipes Instead of us making fiddles showing that it works, why don't you make a fiddle showing that it doesn't. Then we can show you where you went wrong.

Comment: Dunno what I was doing wrong earlier, but when I pasted in yr code just now, things were working fine. sorry for doubting. peace

Answer (score 1):

The error is in there

```
$(function(){
  $('.featured-promo a:gt(0)').hide();
   setInterval(function(){
     $('.featured-promo :first-child')// here
     .hide()
     .next('a')
     .fadeIn(2000)
     .end()
     .appendTo('.featured-promo');// no need to append as the for loop is already appending the anchors to the featured-promo.
   }, 1000);
)};
```

You are calling the `.next('a')` on `.featured-promo` first-child which is not a sibling of `.featured-promo` but it's child.
`elementA.next()` is used to get the sibling(the element after the elementA ie, element B)

To get the other `a`s' you should write like this

```
$(function(){
  var index = 0;
  var total_a = $('.featured-promo a').length;
   setInterval(function(){
     $('.featured-promo a:gt(' + index + ')')
     .hide()
     .next('a')
     .fadeIn(2000);
     index = (index < total_a) ? index + 1 : 0;// will increment if number of a is greater than index else 0 and continue like a slider..
   }, 2000);// better use 2000 ms as you're using 2000ms in the `fadeIn()`
 });
```

Comment: I don't get your point. He doesn't want a sibling of `.featured-promo`, he wants the second child.

Comment: What he was doing was `$('.featured-promo :first-child').next('a') `which gives the next anchor element of `.featured-promo` ( an anchor element which is a sibling of `.featured-promo` ). But what he wanted is to get the next anchor element of the current anchor inside `.featured-promo`.

Comment: He always wants to get the second anchor element. The `appendTo()` moves the first anchor to the end of the list, so the second anchor becomes the first one when it fades in.

Comment: Ah ok, but he will neither get the desired anchor with the `$('.featured-promo :first-child').next('a');` as he's not traversing inside the `.featured-promo` to get the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('.featured-promo a:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
    $('.featured-promo :first-child')
    .hide()
    .find('a')
    .fadeIn(2000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('.featured-promo');
}, 1000);
```

Try find instead of next

Answer (score 0):

Use end() after hide():

```
$('.featured-promo :first-child')
        .hide()
        .end()
        .next('a')
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('.featured-promo');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(function(){
    $('.featured-promo a:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.featured-promo').children('a .featured-print').eq(1).parent()
        .hide()
        .next('a')
        .fadeIn(2000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('.featured-prints');
}, 1000);
```

Comment: `.featured-print` is not a child of `.featured-promo`, it's a grand-child.

Comment: @Barmar sorry, fixed it!